# Passing row and column name to get value

Tags: python, pandas

I have an csv file  like
[CSV File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Gbty.png)

I want to get values based on row and column names . For example  if I pass C2 & T2 , I should be able to fetch respective value = 6. 
How this can be done in pandas.

Comment: did u try this? http://pythonhow.com/accessing-dataframe-columns-rows-and-cells

Comment: For your case, it would be - `df.at['T2','C2']` (or) `df.get_value('T2','C2')`

Comment: Adding to @NickilMaveli 's answer, for that to work, your index has to be the Ts column. From the image you provided, that column has no name. You could add Ts or T or something like that in the first cell so that it won't be unnamed and then do `df = pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv', index_col='Ts')`.